# Was there an unsuccessful raid by a SWAT team on the CyberBunker?

Tags: law-enforcement, netherlands, police

According to [CyberBunker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyberBunker), a [Dutch Police SWAT team attempted a raid on their property](https://www.cyberbunker.com/web/swat.php) but were so unsuccessful in gaining entry that staff didn't even notice the attempts until they reviewed the security footage later that afternoon.

After the DDoS attacks aimed at Spamhaus last year, many stories were written about CyberBunker which repeated this claim.

[image: Dutch police in riot gear in front of a bunker]
<sub>This photo illustrating the article on CyberBunker's site is an relatively obvious composite of Dutch police in riot gear in the foreground and a bunker in the background and is probably not evidence of anything.</sub>

---

- Does the security footage that they threatened to release exist anywhere on the internet?
- Is there any record of the €8088 they claim was paid to them by the Dutch police for repairing their fence?
- Did the reporter they claim was there ever report anything?

I'm skeptical that the event happened as described and possibly that it happened at all.  Is there any independent evidence of this event?

Comment: BTW. cops on the photo are riot police can expect too see during football matches, but not during raid on high-tech data center. As for reporting, there isn't a single one that would mention that in other context, than quote with disclaimer *"as CyberBunker claims on their website"*. But of course proving non-existence of something is something that can be done easily.

Comment: The Dutch police has no dedicated SWAT teams. The unit shown are indeed normal riot police, who might be deployed as part of a larger police operation for crowd control if such is expected to be required. The closest thing to a SWAT team there is in the Netherlands is a small anti-terrorism unit.